# javascript - 'arrpf[i][1]' is null or not an object IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a js loop statement where it doesn't happen to work on IE8.
this is what it's showing 'data' is null or not an object.
Not sure where and what I'm doing something wrong here.
any help or tips would be great.thank you all

```js
pfhtml = "";

for (i = 0; i < arrpf.length; i++) {
    ctr = -1;
    for (j = 0;j < arrPfCount.length;j++) {
        if (arrpf[i][1] == arrPfCount[j][0]) {
            ctr = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ctr > -1) {
        pfhtml += "<option value='" + arrpf[i][1] + "'>" + arrpf[i][0] + " [" + arrPfCount[ctr][1] + "]</option>";
    }
}

$("#industry").append(pfhtml);
```

Comment: The symbol `data` doesn't appear in that code.

Comment: @Pointy sorry the 'arrpf[i][1]' not 'Data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a trailing comma in the definition of arrpf?

IE 8 and below treat an array of [1,2,3,] as [1,2,3,undefined] - unlike other browsers which treat it as [1,2,3]. This code shows the difference when you run it in IE 8:

```
    <ul>
        <script>
            var arr = ["a", "b", "c", ];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                document.write("<li>" + typeof (arr[i]) + "</li>");
            }
        </script>
    </ul>
```